# gcloud beta compute vpn-tunnels list output is not being formatted as a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cmd

> gcloud beta compute vpn-tunnels list
>
> NAME: on-prem-tunnel0 REGION: us-central1 GATEWAY: on-prem-vpn-gw1
> PEER_ADDRESS: 35.242.102.18
>
> NAME: on-prem-tunnel1 REGION: us-central1 GATEWAY: on-prem-vpn-gw1
> PEER_ADDRESS: 35.220.71.15
>
> NAME: vpc-demo-tunnel0 REGION: us-central1 GATEWAY: vpc-demo-vpn-gw1
> PEER_ADDRESS: 35.242.122.148
>
> NAME: vpc-demo-tunnel1 REGION: us-central1 GATEWAY: vpc-demo-vpn-gw1
> PEER_ADDRESS: 35.220.74.245

i run this

> gcloud beta compute vpn-tunnels list --format=table

ERROR: (gcloud.beta.compute.vpn-tunnels.list) Format [table] requires a non-empty projection

Answer (score 0):

The error **Format [table] requires a non-empty projection** means you did not include a value.

Projections are used to define the structure and what data to include in the table.

Example:

```
gcloud beta compute vpn-tunnels list \
--project [PROJECT_ID] \
--format="table[box,title=VPN-Tunnels](name)"
```